# Document gets updated without any request in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am writing a verification logic where I email a link to the users and when they click on it the users get verified but for some reason the users get verified before clicking on the link

Here is my code to register users

```js
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const emailExists = await Users.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (emailExists)
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ status: "error", error: "Email already exists", type: "email" });

  if (!verifyEmail(req.body.email)) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ status: "error", error: "Enter a valid email", type: "email" });
  }

  if (req.body.password.length < 6) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      status: "error",
      error: "Password should be atleast 6 chr long",
      type: "password",
    });
  }

  var user = new Users({
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    sex: req.body.sex,
    dob: req.body.dob,
    rss: req.body.rss,
    isloggedin: false,
    isverified: false,
  });

  var savedUser = await user.save();

  let mailDetails = {
    from: "<email>",
    to: req.body.email,
    subject: "Verify your email",
    text: "Click on this link to verify your email: ",
    html: "<br><h2>Hello " + req.body.firstName + "</h2><a href='https://<my link>/verify/" + savedUser._id + "'>Verify</a>",
  };

  mailTransporter.sendMail(mailDetails, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log("Email sent successfully");
  });

  res.json({ status: "ok" });
});
```

Here is my verification code:

```js
app.get("/verify/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  
  console.log("How did this get executed?")
  console.log(id)
  
  const update = { isverified: true };
  var x = await Users.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, update, function (err, docs) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("THERES A UPDATE VERIFICATION ERROR");
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      console.log("Updated User : ", docs);
    }
  }).clone();
  //For some reason the above code executes twice and it throws a mongoose error when you add .clone() method it would still call
  //itself twice but it won't throw any error
  //Why does the above code execute twice?
  
  res.send("You have been verified, visit the login page to login to the app <script>location.assign('/login');</script>");
});
```

At first I thought that gmail is clicking my link to check it but I verified that it doesnt do that.
Also for some reason the verification code executes twice (that's why the extra `.clone()` method)

Comment: do you mean the GET endpoint gets executed even when no request is made to it ?

Comment: Yes, whenever the `/register` route is executed and the mail in sent in the last the `/verify/:id` (GET endpoint) gets executed after it even when I have not clicked the link

Answer (score 1):

You mixed `async` syntax with the `callback` syntax. Also, you have to specify `{ new: true }`, on the update query in order for query to return updated document. If you don't specify it, the query will return the document state before the update.

Try this:

```
app.get("/verify/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  try {
    const user = await Users.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { isverified: true }, { new: true });
    console.log("Updated User : ", user );
    return res.status(200).send("You have been verified, visit the login page to login to the app <script>location.assign('/login');</script>");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('ERROR: ', error);
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing that out, I tried your solution but the code still updates the user without me clicking on the link in my mail and the `findByIdAndUpdate` method still runs twice. Do you think that gmail clicks the links that I send? Because the update also happens after I get the mail

Comment: Hello @NeNaD, could you please guide me on what else could be the problem. Thanks